# Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

While upgrading spring boot parent from 2.5.10 -> 2.6.6 and spring cloud version from 2020.0.3 -> 2021.0.1 getting the application start error while deploying in k8s. Its running fine in local. Any help on fix?

Have upgraded many application with spring cloud stream eventhub. But this one has kafka binder and gives the error on app start
pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx.rms.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>rm-purchase-order-processor</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <azure.version>3.6.0</azure.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx.rms</groupId>
            <artifactId>rm-common-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.44-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-eventhubs</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

App Log

```
2022-05-03 06:30:38.022 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at com.xxx.rms.PurchaseOrderProcessorApplication.main(PurchaseOrderProcessorApplication.java:16) [classes!/:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [app.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) [app.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [app.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [app.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.springframework.integration.support.json.JacksonJsonUtils.<clinit>(JacksonJsonUtils.java:58) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar!/:5.5.10]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.<init>(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:139) ~[spring-integration-kafka-5.5.10.jar!/:5.5.10]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:735) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:163) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:426) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:92) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindConsumer(BindingService.java:180) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:137) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
```

Dependancy tree

```
[] com.xxx.rms.test:rm-purchase-order-processor:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[] +- com.xxx.rms:rm-common-lib:jar:0.0.44-SNAPSHOT:compile
[] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.2:compile
[] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile
[] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.2:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.17:compile
[] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.17:compile
[] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |     \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.16:compile
[] |        \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.8.4:compile
[] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[] +- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:jar:1.8.4:runtime
[] |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:jar:0.12.0:runtime
[] |     \- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.12.0:runtime
[] |        +- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_otel:jar:0.12.0:runtime
[] |        |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_common:jar:0.12.0:runtime
[] |        \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_otel_agent:jar:0.12.0:runtime
[] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.60:compile
[] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.60:compile
[] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.60:compile
[] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11:compile
[] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.6.6:runtime (optional) 
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.22:compile (optional) 
[] +- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.6.0:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  \- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot:jar:3.6.0:compile
[] |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[] |     \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[] +- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-eventhubs:jar:2.5.0:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:jar:3.2.2:compile
[] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |  |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:5.5.10:compile
[] |  |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:jar:5.5.10:compile
[] |  |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.3.2:compile
[] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context:jar:3.2.2:compile
[] |  |     +- net.jodah:typetools:jar:0.6.2:compile
[] |  |     \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[] |  +- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-starter-eventhubs:jar:2.5.0:compile
[] |  |  +- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-integration-eventhubs:jar:2.5.0:compile
[] |  |  |  \- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-integration-core:jar:2.5.0:compile
[] |  |  |     \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[] |  |  \- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-messaging:jar:2.5.0:compile
[] |  |     \- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-context:jar:2.5.0:compile
[] |  |        +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.6.6:compile
[] |  |        |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[] |  |        +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[] |  |        +- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-telemetry:jar:2.5.0:compile
[] |  |        +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-resources:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  |  \- com.azure:azure-core-management:jar:1.2.1:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-storage:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-compute:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-network:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-keyvault:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  |  +- com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-keys:jar:4.2.7:compile
[] |  |        |  |  \- com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-secrets:jar:4.3.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-msi:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-sql:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-authorization:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-appservice:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-cosmos:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-containerservice:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-monitor:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-containerregistry:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-dns:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-appplatform:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  |  \- com.azure:azure-storage-file-share:jar:12.10.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-containerinstance:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-privatedns:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-redis:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-eventhubs:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-trafficmanager:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-servicebus:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  +- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-cdn:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        |  \- com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-search:jar:2.4.0:compile
[] |  |        \- com.azure.spring:azure-identity-spring:jar:1.5.0:compile
[] |  |           \- com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.3.1:compile
[] |  |              +- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:jar:1.10.1:compile
[] |  |              |  \- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:9.7:compile
[] |  |              |     +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[] |  |              |     +- com.nimbusds:content-type:jar:2.1:compile
[] |  |              |     +- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.5:compile
[] |  |              |     \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.9.3:compile
[] |  |              +- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:jar:1.1.0:compile
[] |  |              |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.5.0:compile
[] |  |              +- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.6.0:compile
[] |  |              \- org.linguafranca.pwdb:KeePassJava2:jar:2.1.4:compile
[] |  |                 +- org.linguafranca.pwdb:KeePassJava2-kdb:jar:2.1.4:compile
[] |  |                 |  +- org.linguafranca.pwdb:database:jar:2.1.4:compile
[] |  |                 |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[] |  |                 |  |  \- com.madgag.spongycastle:core:jar:1.54.0.0:compile
[] |  |                 |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:15.0:compile
[] |  |                 +- org.linguafranca.pwdb:KeePassJava2-dom:jar:2.1.4:compile
[] |  |                 |  \- org.linguafranca.pwdb:KeePassJava2-kdbx:jar:2.1.4:compile
[] |  |                 +- org.linguafranca.pwdb:KeePassJava2-jaxb:jar:2.1.4:compile
[] |  |                 \- org.linguafranca.pwdb:KeePassJava2-simple:jar:2.1.4:compile
[] |  |                    +- org.simpleframework:simple-xml:jar:2.7.1:compile
[] |  |                    |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[] |  |                    |  +- stax:stax:jar:1.2.0:compile
[] |  |                    |  \- xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.3.3:compile
[] |  |                    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
[] |  |                    \- com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:jar:1.0.0:compile
[] |  \- com.azure:azure-messaging-eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob:jar:1.7.0:compile
[] |     +- com.azure:azure-messaging-eventhubs:jar:5.7.1:compile
[] |     |  +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.17.0:compile
[] |     |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.13.2:compile
[] |     |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[] |     |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.7:compile
[] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.51.Final:compile
[] |     |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-classes:jar:2.0.51.Final:compile
[] |     |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-x86_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[] |     |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-aarch_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[] |     |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-x86_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[] |     |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-aarch_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[] |     |  |     \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:windows-x86_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[] |     |  \- com.azure:azure-core-amqp:jar:2.0.5:compile
[] |     |     +- com.microsoft.azure:qpid-proton-j-extensions:jar:1.2.3:compile
[] |     |     \- org.apache.qpid:proton-j:jar:0.33.4:compile
[] |     \- com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.12.0:compile
[] |        +- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.10.0:compile
[] |        |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |        |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[] |        |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:1.0.17:compile
[] |        |     +- io.projectreactor.netty.incubator:reactor-netty-incubator-quic:jar:0.0.6:runtime
[] |        |     |  \- io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-native-quic:jar:linux-x86_64:0.0.26.Final:runtime
[] |        |     |     \- io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-classes-quic:jar:0.0.26.Final:runtime
[] |        |     |        \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[] |        |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http-brave:jar:1.0.17:runtime
[] |        |        \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.13.7:runtime
[] |        |           \- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.13.7:runtime
[] |        |              \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave:jar:2.16.3:runtime
[] |        |                 \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.16.3:runtime
[] |        |                    \- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.23.2:runtime
[] |        +- com.azure:azure-storage-common:jar:12.12.0:compile
[] |        \- com.azure:azure-storage-internal-avro:jar:12.0.5:compile
[] +- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-test:jar:2.6.0:test
[] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-test:jar:3.2.2:test
[] |  |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test:jar:5.5.10:test
[] |  |     \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test-support:jar:5.5.10:test
[] |  |        \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:2.2:test
[] |  +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
[] |  |     \- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0:test
[] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22:test
[] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22:test
[] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:2.0.2:test
[] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:2.0.2:test
[] |  |     +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:2.0.2:test
[] |  |     \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:2.0.2:test
[] |  |        \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:test
[] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:2.0.2:test
[] |  |  +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:2.0.2:test
[] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.3.Final:compile
[] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[] |  +- com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.0:compile
[] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.2:compile
[] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.2.2:compile
[] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.2:compile
[] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support:jar:3.2.2:test 
[] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.6.6:test
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.6:test
[] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:test
[] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:test
[] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.21.0:test
[] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.0.0:test
[] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.18:compile
[] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.18:test
[] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4:test
[] +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:jar:1.8.0-M1:test
[] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.1:test
[] |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.8.2:test
[] |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:jar:1.8.2:test
[] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[] \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:jar:3.2.2:compile
[]    +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[]    |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:jar:5.5.10:compile
[]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.0.1:compile
[]    |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.0-2:runtime
[]    |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[]    |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.1:runtime
[]    \- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.8.4:compile
[]       +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.18:compile
[]       \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:runtime
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug in spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar, it incorrectly uses `List.of` which was added in Java 9; you are probably using a newer JDK locally and JDK8 in k8s.

It is fixed in 5.5.11 which comes with 2021.0.2.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to get out of my several day rut. Lifesaving!